# XML data retrieved from urlopen replaces "<" and ">" with ";"

Tags: python, xml

I am retrieving data from a url as:

`data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()`

However, I noticed that there are no tags. This was because the "<" and ">" were replaced by ";" character. Everything else is intact.
So:

`<foo>bar</foo>` is changed to `;foo;bar;/foo;`

How can I fix this and why is it happening?

[EDIT]: I found out how to fix it. Apparently, it was replacing '<' with '&lt' and '>' with '&gt'. I guess the short forms of the signs. I still don't know why this is happening. I guess some bug in the webservice/API.

Comment: What's the source of the XML?

Comment: That is *never* caused by `urllib2`. Are you 100% certain the server didn't produce that data?

Comment: When I open the url in IE or FF I can see the tags just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this:

```
    import urllib2

    url='http://www.google.com'
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    print data
```

And I get plenty of < and >, including the last line `</script></body></html>`

Can you post a few more details like the url you're trying to access and the value of `data`?

Comment: the link and the data are both confidential since they exist at my work. I will however, remove sensitive information and post the data.

Comment: Did you try the above and grab Google's main page? Are you getting `<` or `;`?

Comment: i tried at home and it works fine. But can only try at work tomorrow.